# Karate UI test not working as reference eval is failed

Tags: karate

I'm using karate-apache 0.9.4 jar in pom.xml and trying to automate the login for an angular application exposed in local machine

But irrespective of commands used keep getting same error and script s failed

> Error: JavaScript evaluation failed : wait
>   until("document.readystate=='complete'"), reference error : waitUntil
>   is defined in eval at line number 1  Steps in feature file are

Given driver 'http://1x.37d.37x.34b:1234'
* waitUntil("document.readystate=='complete'")